# Return copies of dictionary modified

Tags: python, lambda

I have a dictionary and for a particular key, I have say 5 possible new values. So I am trying to create 5 copies of the original dictionary by using a simple lambda function that will replace the value of that particular key and return a copy of the master dictionary.

```
# This is the master dictionary.
d = {'fn' : 'Joseph', 'ln' : 'Randall', 'phone' : '100' }
# Joseph has got 4 other phone numbers
lst = ['200', '300', '400', '500']
# I want 4 copies of the dictionary d with these different phone numbers
# Later I would want to do some processing with those dictionary without affecting d
```

So I am trying to do this:

```
# y is the list I want to hold these copies of dictionaries with modified values
i = d.copy()
y = map( lambda x : (i.update({'phone' : x})) and i, lst )
```

I thought this would return a list of dictionaries and each of them would have phone number changed to 200, 300, 400 and 500 respectively. I can put a loop and create copies and change them using a naive approach, but I want to explore and know how I can exploit the lambdas to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Marcin: "I want to explore and know how I can exploit the lambdas to accomplish this".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'fn' : 'Joseph', 'ln' : 'Randall', 'phone' : '100' }
>>> lst = ['200', '300', '400', '500']
>>> [dict(d, phone=x) for x in lst]
[{'ln': 'Randall', 'phone': '200', 'fn': 'Joseph'}, {'ln': 'Randall', 'phone': '300', 'fn': 'Joseph'}, {'ln': 'Randall', 'phone': '400', 'fn': 'Joseph'}, {'ln': 'Randall', 'phone': '500', 'fn': 'Joseph'}]
```

If you still insist on using `map` and a lambda (which does exactly the same, only a bit slower):

```
>>> map(lambda x: dict(d, phone=x), lst)
[{'ln': 'Randall', 'phone': '200', 'fn': 'Joseph'}, {'ln': 'Randall', 'phone': '300', 'fn': 'Joseph'}, {'ln': 'Randall', 'phone': '400', 'fn': 'Joseph'}, {'ln': 'Randall', 'phone': '500', 'fn': 'Joseph'}]
```

By the way, the reason why your approach didn't work as expected is because `.update()` modifies the dictionary in place, rather than creating a new dictionary that reflects the update. It also doesn't return the result, so the lambda evaluates to `None` (and you probably got back a list like `[None, None, None, None]`.

Comment: (+1) This is much better than my suggestion.

Comment: @aix: Thanks :) I learned that trick recently on SO, this is really a great site!

Comment: Right. I got back a list of 'None' when I tried the OP. 
Great! Thanks :-)
The list comprehension is way too cool. No stopping getting astonished with how cool python is.